# Geyser drains when removing tap

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

A few weeks ago, I replaced the mixer tap at my kitchen basin. I turned off the water at the meter outside, opened the cold water tap to empty the pipes, and removed the cold water connection.

All good. But when I unscrewed the the hot water connection, the whole geyser started draining out, all 200 liters (about 50 US gallons) of it.

Yes, the geyser is in the roof (and not so easy to get to), so I get that gravity should draw the water down, but shouldn't turning off the geyser's water supply prevent it from draining? What's the best way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume "Geyser" means hot water heater tank.

If you turn a jug of milk upside down the milk drains out.  So will any container of water with a pipe in the bottom.

You should have local shutoff valves to prevent this, or a valve at the outlet of the tank.

Comment: By "hot water tank", I assume you mean geyser 
I spoke to a plumber, and understood it's supposed to have a non-return valve installed to prevent the drain. Clearly, mine either doesn't have that valve, or it's defective.

Comment: Do you at least have a supply cutoff *before* the "geyser?"  Otherwise you're gonna have to get the city to turn off the water at the service connection.